# Как указать, что длина VARCHAR2 для текста юникода в символах, а не в байтах?

Tags: sql, oracle, unicode

[Соглсано этой спецификации](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-varchar2) `VARCHAR2(max_size CHAR)` должен хранить `max_size` кол-во символов. Но наблюдаю другое/противоположенное поведение для  текстов с юникод символами.

Например, следуюий пример:

```
create table test (id varchar2(3 char) not null, primary key (id));

insert into test(id) values('abc');

1 row(s) affected.

insert into test(id) values('ффф');
```

> Query 1 ERROR: ORA-12899: value too large for column "TEST"."TEST"."ID" (actual: 6, maximum: 3)

Получается, что `VARCHAR2(3 chars)` на самом деле то же самое, что и байт? Но это же НЕ ТАК:

```
create table test (id varchar2(3 byte) not null, primary key (id));

insert into test(id) values('ффф');
```

> Query 1 ERROR: ORA-12899: value too large for column "OSB_TRUNK"."TEST"."ID" (actual: 18, maximum: 3)

И вопрос остается, как указать, что длина `VARCHAR2` для текста юникода в символах (точнее UTF8)?

---

PS Использую TablePlus, DBeaver или JDBC (thin) драйвер. Дамп после вставки:

```
Typ=1 Len=6 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: ef,bf,bd,ef,bf,bd
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle varchar2 and unicode texts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65230784) от участника [@FoxyBOA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19347/foxyboa)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65230784

Answer (score 2):

Приведенный пример в вопросе рабочий:

```
SQL> select * from v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'nls_characterset'
/
PARAMETER           VALUE      
------------------- -----------
NLS_CHARACTERSET    AL32UTF8   

SQL> create table test (id varchar2 (3 char));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test(id) values('abc');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test(id) values('ффф');

1 row created.
```

Похоже, используемый клиент использует неправильные настройки кодировки символов.

Символ: ф ([U+0444: Cyrillic Small Letter Ef](https://unicode-table.com/en/0444/)), имеет следующие значения:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Encoding|hex        |dec (bytes)|dec       |binary                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|UTF-8   |D1 84      |209 132    |53636     |11010001 10000100                  |
|UTF-16BE|04 44      |4 68       |1092      |00000100 01000100                  |
|UTF-16LE|44 04      |68 4       |17412     |01000100 00000100                  |
|UTF-32BE|00 00 04 44|0 0 4 68   |1092      |00000000 00000000 00000100 01000100|
|UTF-32LE|44 04 00 00|68 4 0 0   |1141112832|01000100 00000100 00000000 00000000|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

То есть, `DUMP` должен вернуть:

```
Typ=1 Len=6 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: d1,84,d1,84,d1,84
```

Но в действительноости в дампе символ - `ef,bf,bd`, [U+FFFD: Replacement Character](https://unicode-table.com/en/FFFD/)

То есть, вставка значения `ффф`, конвертируется в `���`.

Полагаю, что на самом деле клиент использует UTF-8, но не устанавливает эту кодировку для сессии БД. Поэтому, используется кодировка по умолчанию `US7ASCII`. Клиент посылает 6 байт (`d1,84,d1,84,d1,84`), но они интерпретируются как 6 однобайтных символов, один из которых недействительный.

Обычно, используется переменная окружения `NLS_LANG`, чтобы установить кодировку. Однако, *DBeaver* использует Java/JDBC, который не использует настройки `NLS_LANG` (по крайней мере, по умолчанию).

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65233475) от участника [Wernfried Domscheit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried-domscheit)</sub>

Comment: @MaxU Не знаю, надо будет попробовать.